# Can I change what double clicking the Surface pen button does?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-surface-pro-3, pen

I know about [Is it possible to change the application opened by the Surface Pro 3's pen button?](https://superuser.com/q/777199/41443) which covers what happens with a single click of the purple pen button. However I just read [a review of the Surface 4 pen](http://www.windowscentral.com/3-essential-shortcuts-new-surface-pen) which reveals that double clicking the pen button takes a screenshot. I just tested with my Surface 3 and its pen, and this works, sort of.

- It does the same as <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>PrtScrn</kbd>, which is to say full screen, not just the active window (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>PrtScrn</kbd> gets the active window) and if you have multiple screens, all of them
- it seems to leave you in a kind of weird state until you click the button once more to launch OneNote

As such it's less useful than knowing the Type Cover shortcut for a screen print (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> if you were wondering). But if I could adjust it to do the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>PrtScrn</kbd> thing, and not have to launch OneNote afterwards, that would be ok by me.

So: how can I control the double click action of the Surface Pen purple button, ideally for my Surface 3?

Comment: [There is an application for the pen that comes with the Surface Pro 3 that allows you to configure the buttons on it.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/surface/9wzdncrfjb8p)  As for it supporting the new pen that has not yet been released, the application, eventually will be updated I am sure.  So the application might have been updated to only support Windows 10, it did exist, and that is how you would have done it if that is the case.

Comment: That allows me to choose which kind of OneNote I want to launch on a single click, and makes no mention of a double click action

Comment: And I can get screenshots now on a Surface Pro 3 with a 3 pen, running 8.1, so I don't need new hardware or software to get screenshots. Since they don't let me control that setting now I doubt they will in 10 either.

Comment: If that is the case then that particular action cannot be reconfigured.  I only mention Windows 10 because the web portal for the application indicated it required Windows 10.